# Global alignment

Tags: equations, align, amsmath, cases

I'm trying to do some sort of global alignment for my equations and didn't succeed to find anything online. More precisely, my `cases` environment inside my `aligned` and `equation*` has its own `&` alignment-symbols that I want to be working with other ones inside `aligned`. Hopefully this MWE (using `amsmath`) makes it understandable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
                    & \left| f_{(x)} \right| &\overset{!}{\leq} &L \left| x - y \right| &                      \\
    \Leftrightarrow & \left| x - y \right|   &\leq              &L \left| x - y \right| &                      \\
    \Leftrightarrow & \begin{cases}
                      x - y                  &\leq              &L (x - y)              &\text{ for } x \geq y \\
                      y - x                  &\leq              &L (y - x)              &\text{ for } x > y    \\
                      \end{cases}                                                                              \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

**How do I align every part over each other like the `&`s in the code above?**

Thank you for any hints. *I'm also happy for feedback on my code-style :)*

*Extra question:* Why do I get an *"Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr."* and an *"underfull hbox"* at the very end?

*Similar questions **not** answering mine:*

- [Align equations which already have aligned answers (alignment-ception)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288630/align-equations-which-already-have-aligned-answers-alignment-ception): actually no (in)ception like promised in the title - Christopher Nolan would be disapointed.
- [aligning a multiline formula with the bullet of itemize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4423/aligning-a-multiline-formula-with-the-bullet-of-itemize): uses `itemize`
- [left-justified text in the same line as the beginning of \align equations [duplicate]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405726/align-the-number-of-an-enumerated-list-with-an-equation-with-cases): actually aligning `labels`

Comment: It's not quite a MWE. A MWE is to be typeset "out of the box", so it must have `\documentclass{}`, the necessary packages, `\begin{document}` and so on…

Comment: @FranckPastor done, thanks for pointing out!

Comment: The _cases_ environment defines a box of its own IIRC, so I can't see how it can be managed this way. By the way, this environment doesn't accept more than one ampersand per line, so your code can't be typeset as it is.

Comment: Methinks you are trying too align too much. Is that *really* necessary?

Comment: @FranckPastor, again, thank you. That will probably mean that I'm dropping the use of `cases` then and have to go for doing it by myself...

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen as long as it looks better and even enhances readability, I will always go for more alignment. But I understand your point. With `cases` only supporting one ampersand I suppose more LaTeX users/developpers think like you about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
                    && | f_{(x)}| &\overset{!}{\leq} L | x - y | &                      \\
    &{\Leftrightarrow} & | x - y | &\leq          L | x - y | &                      \\
    &\smash{\raisebox{-8pt}{$\Leftrightarrow\biggl\{$}}
                    &  x - y    &\leq   L (x - y)   &\text{ for } x \geq y \\
                     &&y - x     &\leq   L (y - x)   &\text{ for } x > y                          
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow this just looks perfect as imagined. After reading [about alignedat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203963/spacing-in-alignat-and-alignedat#203966) and learning about `cases` only supporting one ampersand, I guess doing it all manually is the only option. However, and don't get me wrong on this, I really don't like `raisebox` and `biggl\{` instead of dynamical parantheses like `\left\{`. I guess nesting two multline boxes will be the way to go...

Comment: @4ster it's almost always better to choose the size than use left/right  eg uses such as `\left| x - y \right|` should be avoided.

Comment: that's interesting to hear. I thought keeping everything variable (e.g. allowing to change the documents font size) was a good measure to take - `8pt` in your code didn't seem to comply with that approach. Now I guess I need a good guide for LaTeX-style to change my approach. With your experience, can you recommend something where I can get a deeper understanding of this?

Comment: @4ster see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173717/1090

Answer (score 2):

With some gentle persuasion applied to `bigdelim`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array,bigdelim}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\Nleq}{\overset{!}{\leq}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\reducedelim}{%
  \patchcmd{\@ldelim}{\multirow@dima}{0.75\multirow@dima}{}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{ l r >{{}}c<{{}} l @{\qquad} l }
   & \lvert f_{(x)} \rvert &\Nleq& L \lvert x - y \rvert \\
\Leftrightarrow
   & \lvert x - y \rvert  &\leq&  L \lvert x - y \rvert \\
\reducedelim\ldelim\lbrace{2}{*}[$\Leftrightarrow$\qquad]
   & x - y                 &\leq&  L (x - y) &\text{for $x \geq y$} \\
   & y - x                 &\leq&  L (y - x) &\text{for $x > y$}
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, the middle inequality is satisfied, for all *x* and *y*, if and only if *L* ≥ 1.